# Build Failure for Django-Oscar 3.1.6 Frobshop Assets

Tags: gulp, django-oscar, django-assets

I am working through the [Frobshop sample project](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/internals/getting_started.html) for `django-oscar`.

The `django-oscar` documentation is rather terse regarding customizing assets, and [the unresolved bug I reported for `manage.py oscar_fork_statics`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/3651) just adds to the confusion. This is my (failed) attempt at copying files manually and compiling the assets.

I installed Frobshop in `/var/work/django/frobshop/`.

I installed a virtual environment for `django-oscar` in `/var/work/django/oscar/`, so the asset directory for the distribution is found within that directory, in `lib/python3.8/site-packages/oscar/static/oscar/`. The `README.rst` file in that directory said ``` When building your own project, it is not recommended to use these files straight from the package.  Rather, you should take a static copy of the ``oscar/static/oscar`` folder and commit it into your project. ```

Seemed straightforward, so I typed:

```sh
$ cd /var/work/django
$ mkdir frobshop/frobshop/static/
$ cp -a lib/python3.8/site-packages/oscar/static/oscar/* frobshop/frobshop/static/
```

Next, `README.rst` said: `You can compile the static assets from the root of the project using a make target: make assets`.

```sh
$ make assets
make: *** No rule to make target 'assets'.  Stop.
```

Hmm, that did not work. Is https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/Makefile the proper `Makefile`, I wonder, and where should it be located?

```sh
$ wget -O frobshop/static/Makefile \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/master/Makefile
```

Running `make assets` gave me an error message complaining about a missing `package.json`, so I grabbed it from `django-oscar` also.

```sh
$ wget -O frobshop/static/package.json \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/master/package.json
```

Seemed like I should run `make` from the new `frobshop/frobshop/static/` directory:

```sh
$ (cd frobshop/static/; make assets)
```

Many files were installed, then eventually this message appeared:

```
found 3 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
npm run build

> django-oscar@3.0.0 build /var/work/django/frobshopCamille/frobshop/static
> gulp copy && gulp scss

[11:32:39] No gulpfile found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! django-oscar@3.0.0 build: `gulp copy && gulp scss`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the django-oscar@3.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mslinn/.npm/_logs/2021-02-19T16_32_39_097Z-debug.log
make: *** [Makefile:29: assets] Error 1
```

I do not know what to do with that error. I see a [directory](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/tree/master/gulpfile.js) in `django-oscar` called `gulpfile.js`. Should I copy that somewhere also?

`README.rst` went on to say: ``` If you make changes to Oscar's assets in development, you can run ``npm run watch`` to automatically watch and compile changes to them. ```

```sh
$ (cd frobshop/static/; npm run watch)
```

Of course, that just yields the same error message as before.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for compiling assets (using `make assets`, which runs Gulp tasks) mentioned in `src/oscar/static_src/oscar/README.rst` are actually only meant for when developing/packaging `django-oscar` itself. We will try to make the documentation more clear.

For a project/shop based on django-oscar, you only need to run `./manage.py collectstatic`, to use Oscar's static files without modification, as mentioned here: https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_handle_statics.html#customising-statics

To modify and override Oscar's static files, you in addition need to run `./manage.py oscar_fork_statics`, to copy Oscar's static files into your project. The command is currently broken, but we are working on a fix: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/pull/3657

Comment: How would I manually copy and override Oscar's static files into my project today, without trying to use the broken `./manage.py oscar_fork_statics`?

Comment: When I make a change to an SCSS file it is not reflected on the rendered page, even after a reload. Some framework (like Jekyll) rebuild SCSS automagically. How would I make changes to SCSS visible?

Comment: @MikeSlinn To manually copy the Oscar static files, just: `$ cp -a lib/python3.8/site-packages/oscar/static/* frobshop/static/`. And then add `/var/work/django/frobshop/static/` to your `STATICFILES_DIRS` [setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS).

The fix for `oscar_fork_statics` is now in the `master` branch: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/commit/735db42436df172460ef65139e470bc6860ee60b.

Comment: @MikeSlinn Oscar builds `oscar/css/styles.css` and `oscar/css/dashboard.css` (which it actually uses) from the SCSS files using [Gulp](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/gulpfile.js). If you want to modify the SCSS files, you will need to set up such building infrastructure for your project. If you'd like to use Gulp, you can look at how Oscar itself does it: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/gulpfile.js. There's even a task in there that watches for changes in the SCSS files, and rebuilds the CSS automatically.